# Why foreground Service not working after removing app from the background?

Tags: java, android

I have been trying to implement foreground service to get location after every 3 sec even when the app is in the background by showing a notification. But when I remove my app from the background notification also removes. However, this is only occurring when I am doing it in MI REDMI NOTE 5(API version 28) and MI REDMI NOTE 4(API version 24) but when I ran the same app in Samsung J5(API version 23), the notification is showing even when the app is removed from background until it is manually stopped from the activity. Is the varied result behavior is due to change in API or is it because of different phone model?

Here's my Service Class

```
package com.example.locationrunandall;

import android.app.Notification;
import android.app.NotificationChannel;
import android.app.NotificationManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.HandlerThread;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.core.app.NotificationCompat;
import androidx.localbroadcastmanager.content.LocalBroadcastManager;

import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationResult;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;

public class ForeService extends Service {


    private static final String PACKAGE_NAME =
            "com.example.customizedforeground";

    static final String ACTION_BROADCAST = PACKAGE_NAME + ".broadcast";
    static final String EXTRA_LOCATION = PACKAGE_NAME + ".location";
    private static final String EXTRA_STARTED_FROM_NOTIFICATION = PACKAGE_NAME +
            ".started_from_notification";
    private Handler mServiceHandler;
    private NotificationManager mNotificationManager;
   // private Notification notification;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private LocationCallback mLocationCallback;
    private Location mLocation;
    private static final String CHANNEL_ID = "CHANNEL_ONE";
    private static final int NOTIFICATION_ID = 4567123;
    private static final String TAG = "123";
    String loc;

    public ForeService(){}

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
      mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);
      mLocationCallback = new LocationCallback(){
    @Override
    public void onLocationResult(LocationResult locationResult) {
        super.onLocationResult(locationResult);
      //Do Location Work You Want To Do
        onNewLocation(locationResult.getLastLocation());
    }
};
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(3*1000);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1000);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        getLastLocation();
        HandlerThread handlerThread = new HandlerThread("HANDLER");
        handlerThread.start();
        mServiceHandler = new Handler(handlerThread.getLooper());
        mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        CharSequence name = "Name Charseq";
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>= Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            NotificationChannel notificationChannel = new
                    NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID,name, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);

            mNotificationManager.createNotificationChannel(notificationChannel);
        }
        startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,getNotification());
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
       // startForeground(NOTIFICATION_ID,getNotification());
        return START_NOT_STICKY;
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        mServiceHandler.removeCallbacksAndMessages(null);

        //stopForeground(true);
    }

    @androidx.annotation.Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return null;
    }


    private void getLastLocation() {
        try {
            mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation()
                    .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                            if (task.isSuccessful() && task.getResult() != null) {
                                mLocation = task.getResult();
                            } else {
                                Log.d(TAG, "Failed to get location.");
                            }
                        }
                    });
        } catch (SecurityException unlikely) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Lost location permission." + unlikely);
        }
    }

    private void onNewLocation(Location location) {
        mLocation = location;
        if(mLocation==null)
        Log.d("DSK_OPER","Lat: = "+"Not known");
        else
            Log.d("DSK_OPER"," : "+location.getLatitude());
        //send intent to broadcast reciever
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION_BROADCAST);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_LOCATION, location);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).sendBroadcast(intent);
        // todo - Write More code here
        mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID,getNotification());
    }



    private Notification getNotification() {

        //Intent intent = new Intent(this,MainActivity.class);

        if(mLocation==null)
            loc = "unknown loc";
        else
            loc = String.valueOf(mLocation.getLatitude());

        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
                .setContentTitle("Latitude and longitude")
                .setContentText(" = "+loc)
                .setOngoing(true)
                .setPriority(Notification.PRIORITY_HIGH)
                .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
                .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis());

        // Set the Channel ID for Android O.
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            builder.setChannelId(CHANNEL_ID);
        }
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

Comment: post your code here for service class

Comment: @Quick learner please see the updated question.

Comment: If you can provide me with any working code for getting location in the background it will be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I am using the foreground service for location update after some interval. Foreground service is useful when you wants to update the location if your app is in background but not killed. But this is your responsibility to stop the foreground service when your app is killed. So you just implement the LifeCycleDelegate so that you can start the service when app is in background and stop the service when app is in foreground. and also kill the service when your main activity or HomeActivity is killed.
this is the code for AppLifecycleHandler.

```
internal class AppLifecycleHandler(private val lifeCycleDelegate: LifeCycleDelegate) : Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks,
    ComponentCallbacks2 {

private var appInForeground = false

override fun onActivityPaused(p0: Activity?) {}

/**
 * app resumed
 */
override fun onActivityResumed(p0: Activity?) {
    if (!appInForeground) {
        appInForeground = true
        lifeCycleDelegate.onAppForegrounded()
    }
}

override fun onActivityStarted(p0: Activity?) {
}

override fun onActivityDestroyed(p0: Activity?) {
}

override fun onActivitySaveInstanceState(p0: Activity?, p1: Bundle?) {
}

override fun onActivityStopped(p0: Activity?) {
}

override fun onActivityCreated(p0: Activity?, p1: Bundle?) {
}

override fun onLowMemory() {}

override fun onConfigurationChanged(p0: Configuration?) {}

/**
 * app sent to background
 */
override fun onTrimMemory(level: Int) {
    if (level == ComponentCallbacks2.TRIM_MEMORY_UI_HIDDEN) {
        appInForeground = false
        lifeCycleDelegate.onAppBackgrounded()
    }
}
```

Add this method to your application class 
     private fun registerLifecycleHandler(lifeCycleHandler: AppLifecycleHandler) {
        registerActivityLifecycleCallbacks(lifeCycleHandler)
        registerComponentCallbacks(lifeCycleHandler)
    }

```
override fun getLifecycle(): Lifecycle {
    return mLifecycleRegistry
}
```

implements LifeCycleDelegate in your application class and override the methods

```
internal interface LifeCycleDelegate {
fun onAppBackgrounded()
fun onAppForegrounded()
```

}

create app object in application class

```
val lifeCycleHandler = AppLifecycleHandler(this)
    registerLifecycleHandler(lifeCycleHandler)
```